# Can I download a large file in the background using aiohttp?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I'd like to download a series of large (~200MB) files, and use the time while they're downloading to do some CPU intensive processing. I'm investigating asyncio and aiohttp. My understanding is I can use them to start a large download and then do some heavy computation on the same thread while the download continues in the background.

What I am finding, however, is that the download is paused while the heavy CPU process continues, then resumes as soon as the calculation is done. I include a minimal example below. I visually monitor the process CPU and bandwidth while the script is running. It's clear the download pauses during the ~30s of computation. Am I doing something wrong? Or am I not understanding what aiohttp can do?

```
import asyncio
import time

import aiofiles
import aiohttp


async def download(session):
    url = 'https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2022.10-Linux-s390x.sh'  # 280 MB file
    async with session.get(url) as resp:
        async with aiofiles.open('./tmpfile', mode='wb') as f:
            print('Starting the download')
            data = await resp.read()
            print('Starting the file write')
            await f.write(data)
            print('Download completed')


async def heavy_cpu_load():
    await asyncio.sleep(5)  # make sure the download has started
    print('Starting the computation')
    for i in range(200000000):  # takes about 30 seconds on my laptop.
        i ** 0.5
    print('Finished the computation')


async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        timer = time.time()
        tasks = [download(session), heavy_cpu_load()]
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        print(f'All tasks completed in {time.time() - timer}s')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Try: `tasks = [asyncio.create_task(download(session)), asyncio.create_task(heavy_cpu_load())]`

Comment: Thanks, I just tried that, same result. My understanding is that the gather function will create tasks from the list anyway.

Comment: Is it a multi-core PC?

Comment: Yes the laptop has 4 cores (Windows OS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have a calculation that doesn't need to `await` something, then you can (and should) run it in a separate thread using [loop.run_in_executor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor), so it will run in the background, threading is what enables the computer to run tasks concurrently (although not necessarily completely simultaneous)

```py
import asyncio
import time

import aiofiles
import aiohttp

async def download(session):
    url = 'https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2022.10-Linux-s390x.sh'  # 280 MB file
    async with session.get(url) as resp:
        async with aiofiles.open('./tmpfile', mode='wb') as f:
            print('Starting the download')
            data = await resp.read()
            print('Starting the file write')
            await f.write(data)
            print('Download completed')

# not async
def heavy_cpu_load():
    print('Starting the computation')
    for i in range(200000000):  # takes about 30 seconds on my laptop.
        i ** 0.5
    print('Finished the computation')

async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        timer = time.time()
        tasks = [
            download(session), 
            asyncio.get_running_loop().run_in_executor(None, func=heavy_cpu_load)
        ]
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        print(f'All tasks completed in {time.time() - timer}s')
asyncio.run(main())
```

using `numpy` (which drop the GIL) and `aiohttp` (network also drops the GIL) should allow your calculations and download to run almost in parallel using only threads, an alternative is to use `ProcessPoolExecutor` as outlined in the linked documentation to allow any function to run in parallel that doesn't drop the gil (with a lot of extra limitations).

Comment: Thanks that mostly solves the problem. I see the bandwidth used for the download is reduced to about 7Mbps during the computation period compared to 37Mbps after the computation has finished. Is there a conflict slowing it down? It also doesn't answer my original (more academic) point, can aiohttp not download in the background with a single thread? I thought that was the point of async IO, other operations could be done in the same thread while waiting on IO.

Comment: @rowan_uk if you look into the documentation of loop.run_in_executor you can run the computation in a different process to ensure the download is running at full speed for any function, as there is in fact a small conflict about the GIL that's happening (the python interpreter is only single threaded), this won't happen as much when you are using numpy because it will drop the GIL frequently, where mathematics in pure python doesn't (your toy example doesn't).

Comment: @rowan_uk You could try to use a `ProcessPoolExecutor` with the method suggested by this answer (`.run_in_executor()`) to avoid the GIL multithreading issues.

Comment: OK thanks for the suggestion. I tried with a numpy calculation in place of the CPU load with a `ThreadPoolExecutor` and indeed the download then happened at the full bandwidth. Is there any advantage to using asyncio in this case then? As far as I can see it's not true async IO (in the sense of single threaded concurrency) and is really just a convenient notation to use multithreading.

Comment: @rowan_uk if your computations and IO are related, and you need to do the calculations and send them in small parts, then `asyncIO` will do this with less delay than threading, as the OS won't have to keep switching threads (which is a context switch), but if both actions are unrelated then threading is recommended, basically `asyncIO` is the goto when the OS context switch becomes the bottleneck, which is common when a server is serving thousands of users.

Comment: That's great @Ahmed, thanks for the explanation. Makes it clearer when to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I think what happens is that the `aiohttp` did finish downloading the file, but in order to open it and read it<sup>1</sup>, it needs the `GIL` to release the lock, but the CPU load does not release the `GIL` until it finishes.

**But**, if you put `await asyncio.sleep(0)`<sup>2</sup> after `i ** 0.5` it will work.
`await` just to make sure if someone wants to take control of the GIL.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> resp.read()</sup>
<sup><sup>2</sup> Common practice to release the GIL lock on purpose.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's what I want, for aiohttp to finish downloading the file in the background and then write it to file when the GIL releases from the CPU load. Actually what happens is the download pauses completely during the CPU load process. The load I actually want to put on involves calculations over large numpy arrays where it is not possible to await asyncio.sleep on each iteration through the loop.